# Fetch Data From Two Different DataBase

Tags: php, postgresql

I have two databases :

1. **Admin**

   `Table` : Employee

   `Columns` : id, name, city_id
2. **Connect**

   `Table` : City

   `Columns` : id, name_of_city

I want to join these two tables using `Employee.city_id` & `City.id` columns in postgre database.

How can i do this

Comment: Use the search for goodness sake. There are over a thousand answers related to postgres joins. Also, read [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html). That is what it is there for.

Comment: He's saying that the tables exist in separate databases...

Answer (score 1):

According to [Postgresql FAQ](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_perform_queries_using_multiple_databases.3F) there is no direct way to query a database other than a current one. But you can use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html). dblink is a module which supports connections to other PostgreSQL databases from within a database session.

Comment: That FAQ entry is slightly out of date; on PostgreSQL 9.3 the `postgres_fdw` will do what you want.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't used 9.3 version yet. Anyway, dblink solves this problem for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is possible with the postgres module [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html), which allows you to join across databases.

With that said, when you consider some of the architectural and data integrity issues that go along with maintaining foreign keys across databases, you should probably consider just moving the `city` table, along with it's data, from the `connect` database to the `admin` database.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [`postgres_fdw`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/postgres-fdw.html) available in PostgreSQL 9.3. It's a SQL/MED foreign data wrapper that lets you create "links" to remote tables.

You can link the City table into the Admin database, then query it from normal SQL. PostgreSQL will even do things like run a `WHERE` condition on the *remote* end and only fetch the rows required. It's still a *lot* less efficient than local tables, since lots of join types aren't available and there's overhead in transferring data before using it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
SELECT e.id as emp_id,e.name,e.city_id,c.* FROM 'admin'.'employee' as e ,'connect'.'city' as c WHERE e.city_id = c.id;
```

Comment: HI its not working 
shows error :- schema "connect" does not exist

Comment: change DB name and try